# Phaser 3 - Destroy a tile map

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am working with Phaser 3 and Matter JS. I am dealing with tile maps, and I want to destroy it.

I add a layer with this (homemade) function:

```
_addLayer(tileset, slug, collides = false) {
    if(this.map.getLayer(slug) == null) {
        return null ;
    }

    let layer = this.map.createLayer(slug, tileset, 0, 0) ;
    if(layer == null) {
        return null ;
    }

    if(collides) {
        layer.setCollisionByProperty({ collides: true }) ;
        this.scene.matter.world.convertTilemapLayer(layer) ;
    }

    this._layers[slug] = layer ;

    return layer ;
}
```

This part works fine. I am trying to destroy the layers with:

```
Object.keys(this._layers).forEach(key => {
     this.scene.matter.world.remove(this._layers[key], true)
}) ;
```

But It's not working. I tried many things, but nothing changed. I cannot destroy the layer (which is still visible in the debug mode)

Anyone already dealt with tile map destroying?

Comment: I never used Phaser :) but apparently TilemapLayers have a `destroy()` method, so I'd try `Object.keys(this._layers).forEach(key => this._layers[key].destroy());` -- https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.52.0/Phaser.Tilemaps.TilemapLayer#destroy

Comment: I already tried this, nothing happened

Comment: I currently don't have a running phaser setup so that I can try it, but in the docu it says, _'As long as no reference to it exists within your own code it should become free for garbage collection by the browser.'_  is there maybe some variable "holding" a reference. https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/focus/Phaser.GameObjects.Layer-destroy